# Pulling data from a JSON file

Tags: json, ruby, hash

Hey I'm trying to print comments in this JSON file:

```
    # https://www.reddit.com/r/android/comments.json?limit=1

    require 'json'

    file = File.read('comments.json')
    data_hash=JSON.parse(file)
    comment = data_hash.fetch("body")
    print comment
```

When I run this it says the body key isn't found?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('comments.json')
data_hash=JSON.parse(file)
require 'pp'
pp data_hash
```

returns

```
{"kind"=>"Listing",
 "data"=>
  {"modhash"=>"",
   "children"=>
    [{"kind"=>"t1",
      "data"=>
       {"subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qlqh",
        "edited"=>false,
        "banned_by"=>nil,
        "removal_reason"=>nil,
        "link_id"=>"t3_5dq9i2",
        "link_author"=>"crazyg0od33",
        "likes"=>nil,
        "replies"=>"",
        "user_reports"=>[],
        "saved"=>false,
        "id"=>"da73zcw",
        "gilded"=>0,
        "archived"=>false,
        "report_reasons"=>nil,
        "author"=>"not_a_miscarriage",
        "parent_id"=>"t1_da73w7s",
        "score"=>1,
        "approved_by"=>nil,
        "over_18"=>false,
        "controversiality"=>0,
        "body"=>"Oh. The more you know",
        "link_title"=>
         "Get the Google Home speaker for $99 at Best Buy on Black Friday",
        "author_flair_css_class"=>nil,
        "downs"=>0,
        "body_html"=>
         "&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Oh. The more you know&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;",
        "quarantine"=>false,
        "subreddit"=>"Android",
        "name"=>"t1_da73zcw",
        "score_hidden"=>true,
        "stickied"=>false,
        "created"=>1479604485.0,
        "author_flair_text"=>nil,
        "link_url"=>"http://blackfriday.bestbuy.com/?category=connected+home2",
        "created_utc"=>1479575685.0,
        "distinguished"=>nil,
        "mod_reports"=>[],
        "num_reports"=>nil,
        "ups"=>1}}],
   "after"=>"t1_da73zcw",
   "before"=>nil}}
```

So the body you're looking for is :

```
data_hash["data"]["children"].first["data"]["body"]
```

With so many hash requests, you probably want to write :

```
data_hash["data"]["children"].first["data"]["body"] rescue ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have json data as a hash in the variable `data_hash` from following code:

```
data_hash=JSON.parse(file)
```

It is just a matter of getting appropriate data key from this hash variable. You are getting this error, as body is not at parent level in the json you are reading, You can get this by following code, which is exact path of body key:

```
>comment = data_hash.fetch("data").fetch("children")[0].fetch("data").fetch("body")

=> "This isn't price match, but price protection via a credit card. They'd issue a check for the difference."
```

You don't necessary need to use `fetch` method here, as `data_hash` is already a hash, so you can simply do following as well:

```
> data_hash["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["body"]   
=> "This isn't price match, but price protection via a credit card. They'd issue a check for the difference."
```

and similarly other data variable can also be accessed.

---

In Ruby 2.3+, you can also do it by simply having:

```
data_hash.dig('data', 'children', 0, 'data', 'body')
```

Comment: `data_hash.dig('data', 'children', 0, 'data', 'body')` also possible in Ruby 2.3+.